# Как проверить исполнялся ли в базе данных некий SQL скрипт на MS SQL Server?

Tags: база-данных

Как проверить исполнялся ли некий SQL скрипт в базе данных? Программа должна сканировать папку на названия файлов и спрашивать у сервера выполнялся ли такой скрипт. Как такое реализовать?

Comment: Что значит "скрипт" в контексте базы данных?

Comment: @vp_arth Некий SQL скрипт изменяющий структуру или данные БД.

Comment: Заведите отдельную таблицу, и пусть ваши скрипты в ней регистрируются

Comment: @vp_arth Правильно и просто, спасибо. Но тут ещё есть нюанс, как отследить какие скрипты были уже исполнены если я пишу ПО для работы с сервером на котором скрипты уже были исполнены. Вопрос всё такой же.

Comment: @vp_arth Это на вопрос не отвечает, но я знаю как это решить, можно прикрутить все имеющиеся скрипты вместе с тем который будет заводить новую таблицу, тогда всё будет решено.

Comment: Ну... на стороне сервера можно, конечно, получить лог запросов через профайлер. Но постоянно работающий Profiler скажется на производительности отнюдь не лучшим образом - в общем, не советую. Разве что для отладки, на недолго...

Comment: Если разово проверить-используйте Profiler. Если постоянно необходимо мониторить, то триггер на inserted, updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно стоит просто создать хранимую процедуру, которая и будет все сохранять.

Comment: Пожалуйста, опишите решение проблемы более детально, чтобы пользователям было легче понять ваш ответ. Для редактирования ответа, нажмите [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как написать хороший ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). - [Из очереди проверок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/149897)